# Google sheets script. Скрыть пустые строки

Tags: javascript, google-spreadsheet, таблицы

Задача такая- есть таблица разбитая на блоки примерно из 600 строк, необходимо скрывать пустые строки при изменении документа. Проблема в том, что функция onEdit имеет ограничение выполнения в 30 сек., соответственно она не успевает пройти по всей таблице. Пробовал другую функцию с использованием триггера по времени, но такой вариант не совсем удобен. Возможно есть какое то другое решение этой задачи?

```
function myFunction1() { ///nascondiRighe
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Таблица ПЗ");
  for (i = 1; i <= 620; i++) {
    var statusRange = ss.getRange("D"+i);
    if (statusRange.getValue() == 0) {
      ss.hideRows(i);
    } else {
      ss.unhideRow(statusRange);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: А зачем скрывать строки по одной? не проще ли применить фильтр?

Comment: Таблица будет постоянно изменяться другими людьми. Необходимо автоматизировать этот процесс. Также некоторые значения в таблице используют формулы с других таблиц.